# How do I clear all old save data and show only last data in core data xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

im new in xcode.
this is my debug said :

```
2012-07-22 18:40:51.787 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Saved for number one
2012-07-22 18:40:55.159 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for test nombre one
2012-07-22 18:40:55.160 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for test number 2
2012-07-22 18:40:55.161 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for test number two
2012-07-22 18:40:55.161 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for test one
2012-07-22 18:40:55.162 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for test again
2012-07-22 18:40:55.163 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for 
2012-07-22 18:40:55.164 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for test one
2012-07-22 18:40:55.165 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for test one again
2012-07-22 18:40:55.166 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for test one again
2012-07-22 18:40:55.166 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for 1
2012-07-22 18:40:55.167 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for (null)
2012-07-22 18:40:55.170 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Successfully load for number one
```

the first line is my input using UITextField, i write "number one" and save it using save button1 using this code and show it this when i press button1

`2012-07-22 18:40:51.787 TestSaveData[2329:fb03] Saved for number one`

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
    TestSaveDataAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    Highscore *record = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Highscore" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    record.highscore1 = textField.text;
    NSLog(@"Saved for %@", textField.text);
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}
```

and when i click button2, my debug view all my old input data. but in my UILabel only show my last input that is "number one" using this button2 below

```
- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender
{
    TestSaveDataAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Highscore" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
    NSArray *array = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    for (Highscore *record in array)
    {
        label.text = record.highscore1;
        NSLog(@"Successfully load for %@", record.highscore1);
    }
}
```

my question is, is there any possible for me to show only last input? in this case if i save "number one" and debug only show "number one" without showing my old data.

Comment: you should not use the `CoreData` for this value only, if you can do, you should use the `NSUserDefaults` to store such an individual value. and for the toplists you could use the `.plist` files without any headache.

Comment: this is only example because i have 4 input data to save and load it all again for next step. please give me suggestion. my data only string and only 4 data for each item. i have 3 items and every item can save 4 list data string and load it when i need it. please teach me. i hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: yep, it is clear. for this you can use **only one** `.plist` file, which contains a combination of `NSMutableArray` objects and `NSMutableDictionary` objects. in this case you can work faster with them than with the `CoreData`.

Comment: yes! i already try it. just like i want it. Thank you! GBU!

Answer (score 0):

You could include a date/time field in your `Highscore` entity, sort by that, and set the `fetchLimit` to 1.  You would be saving the history of scores but only retrieving the latest.